# MS ACCESS Counting Records from table based on multiple criteria

Tags: sql, vba, ms-access

I want a text box in Access to update with the number of records found where a manager has an "overdue" record in the table dependent on the manager selected in a combo box, I have the following code but am getting an error:

```
Private Sub Combo26_AfterUpdate()

Dim rs As DAO.Recordset

Set rs = CurrentDb.OpenRecordset("SELECT Advisor FROM tbltargets WHERE manager = '" & Me.Combo26.Column(0) & "' AND overdue = 'Overdue'")
If rs.EOF Then
Me.Text35 = 0
MsgBox "no overdue records", vbOKOnly
Else
rs.MoveLast
Me.Text35 = rs.RecordCount
rs.Close
End If

End Sub
```

When I select an option from the combo box it gives me an error "Too few parameters. Expected 1"...

I have similar code which works so am unsure why the above is resulting in an error, could anyone help?

Thank you,

Comment: What is Me.Combo26.Column(0) at error?  DCOUNT would be less code  or `select count(advisor) as CT from tblTargets where manager='xyz' and overdue='overdue'`

Comment: thanks for the help.combo 26 is set as the name of the manager in the table when the error occurs.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check like this

```
Private Sub Combo26_AfterUpdate()

Dim rs As DAO.Recordset


If IsNull(Combo26.value) Then Exit Sub

Set rs = CurrentDb.OpenRecordset("SELECT COUNT(*) AS CNT FROM tbltargets WHERE manager = '" & Combo26.value & "' AND overdue = 'Overdue'")

If Not rs.BOF Then

    If Nz(rs!CNT, 0) = 0 Then
        Me.Text35 = 0
        MsgBox "no overdue records", vbOKOnly
    Else
        Me.Text35 = rs!CNT
    End If
End If

End Sub
```

1. Used `combobox.value` instead of `combobox.column`
2. Changed the SQL to `COUNT(*)` and adapted the code accordingly to improve perfs.
3. Added some protection against NULL values (you should really add an Error Handler in this sub)

Comment: Thanks Thomas, I've just given this a go but am getting the same "too few parameters, expected 1" error.

Comment: Set rs = CurrentDb.OpenRecordset("SELECT COUNT(*) AS CNT FROM tbltargets WHERE manager = '" & Combo26.Value & "' AND overdue = 'Overdue'")

Comment: Thomas sorry I found the issue, it was me being completely useless. I am referring to the wrong table. Sorry to have wasted anyones time but your code above has helped regardless and will look to add an error handler as well. Thanks again

Comment: no issue, that happen even to the best... however they arent asking SO :-)